# WordPress post title to be added automatically as a tag

Tags: wordpress, post, tags, title

I have created a CPT and I need the post title to be added automatically as a tag.

Example -

**Post title**: Make them laugh to get them on side

**Tag**: make them laugh to get them on side

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function add_my_tag($id,$post)
{
         wp_set_post_tags($id, str_replace(',', ' ', $post->post_title), true);     //if last argument is false, this will replace current tags, if it's true, it will append.
}
add_action('publish_your-cpt', 'add_my_tag', 7,2);
```

Comment: are you sure you replaced `your_cpt` with correct slug for your custom post type?

Comment: Ah, my bad, I forgot that `publish_` action is type specific. Updated my answer, also, make sure to add post tag support to your custom post type, like so `'taxonomies' => array('post_tag')` when you register it.

Comment: Don't forget to accept answer if it solves your problem. Cheers.